# Calling sub dynamically using perl

Tags: perl, dynamic

I have 4 sub rountines (sub room1 {do stuuf...}, sub room2{do stuff...}, sub room3{do other stuff...}) that will each do different things inside the routine.

What I want to do is to be able to dynamically call a routine based on a variable name.

For exmaple,

> ```
> if ($currentRoom == 1) { &room1; } 
> if ($currentRoom == 2) { &room2; }
> if ($currentRoom == 3) { &room3; }
> ```

What I would rather do, is just call the correct sub routine using $currentRoom as the value after &room.  Something like &room{$currentRoom};

Can this be done and if so, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Perhaps you have subroutine inflation and `room($currentRoom);` would sort this out.

Comment: Use a dispatch table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub test1 {print 1}
sub test2 {print 2}
my $test = 1;
{ # naked block, to make no strict 'refs' not global
  no strict 'refs';
  &{'test'.$test}();
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

but be prepared, if you try to access a sub (e.g. `3` at code above), which does not exists, you will get a warning:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::test3 called at test.pl .....
```

Comment: Thank you that's it.  All I needed to do was &{'room'.$currentRoom};
That has given me exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: note that `&foo;` (with ampersand but without parentheses) is a special form of subroutine call that usually isn't what you mean.  do `&foo();` (or `&{'room'.$currentRoom}();`) instead.

Comment: you are right! Thanks for that, i will edit my answer

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this because it technically answers his question, but this is a terrible idea and should not be used.

Comment: i would use Millers solutions as well. But the OP wanted to know, if there is a **dynamic** way of accessing subs.

Answer (score 17):

Create a hash relating room numbers to subroutine references:

```
my %room_actions = (
    1 => \&room1,
    2 => \&room2,
    3 => \&room3,
);

if ($room_actions{$currentRoom}) {
    $room_actions{$currentRoom}->();
} else {
    die "room doesn't exist: $currentRoom";
}
```

Comment: Cheers thanks.  In this specific case I may have up to 160 of these possible rooms.  Is there any other way to dynamically call the routines.  If not, this will be what I do.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually trying to build, but I  feel a bit strange, having 160 different subroutines for each and every room-number. Are they all that different? Do you really need 160 totally different pieces of code? — You might have to step back and have another look at the problem you want to solve. Surely, lot of these rooms will have a lot in common. You possibly can write one subroutine with `$CurrentRoom` as a parameter. — Miller is right, using a hash for a dispatch-table is usually the way to go. But no matter what solution you would pick, writing 160 subs is lot of work!

Answer (score 1):

This is almost 2 years late, but I landed here after a somehow related search and I was struck by the lack of this solution:

```
__PACKAGE__->can('room' . $currentRoom)->();
```

You can also add some custom error checking:

```
if (my $sub = __PACKAGE__->can('room' . $currentRoom)) {
   $sub->();
}
```

This is a kind of quick and dirty dispatch table, using `can` instead of a hash access but without giving up any safenets.